# Which statistical test should I use to analyse a sample divided into 3 groups?

Tags: statistical-significance

I need to write a research protocol and I can't decided on which test to use so help would be greatly appreciated. We are considering recommending exercise or acupuncture to adult patients with chronic low back pain not adequately managed by paracetamol alone, and we are interested in assessing whether an improvement in pain has been achieved with these interventions. So I will have my control group on paracetamol only, another group on exercise and another one on acupuncture. Which test should I use to analyse my data? I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Many thanks